# How can I make an rxjs Subject repeat its last emission periodically?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to create an rxjs Subject that will repeat its output after a period of inactivity. My initial design was to make use of debounceTime, however that doesn't appear to trigger more than once.

I would like the subject to emit immediately when `next` is called, and repeat that emission periodically until a new value is provided:

```
Inputs:  ---a---------b---------c----
Outputs: ---a---a---a-b---b---b-c---c
```

Currently I have something like so:

```
const subject = new rx.Subject()
subject.debounceTime(5000)
       .subscribe(subject)

subject.subscribe(value => console.log(`emitted: ${value}`))
subject.take(1).subscribe(next => next, error => error, () => {
    console.log('emitted once')
})
subject.take(2).subscribe(next => next, error => error, () => {
    console.log('emitted twice')
})
subject.take(3).subscribe(next => next, error => error, () => {
    console.log('emitted thrice')
})

subject.next('a')
```

However this will only emit 'a' once, and the output 'emitted thrice' is never seen.

Could somebody please help me understand what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use the [`repeatWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeatWhen) operator if I understand your problem correctly:

```
const subject = new ReplaySubject(1);
subject.next('a');

subject
  .take(1)
  .repeatWhen(() => Observable.timer(500, 500))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));

setTimeout(() => subject.next('b'), 1400);
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/nufasiq/2/edit?js,console

This prints to console the following output in 500ms intervals:

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
```

The `take(1)` is necessary here to make the chain complete properly which is intercepted by `repeatWhen()` that subscribes again to its source Observable.

Comment: This is great, thanks. `repeatWhen()` does appear to solve half of the problem, however it appears to _only_ emit when the timer emits. I've merged the original subject and debounced the repeater to produce something that's close enough to what I needed. `subject.merge(subject.debounceTime(1500).take(1).repeatWhen(() => Observable.timer(1500, 1500)))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `switchMap` and `interval`:

```
const source = new Rx.Subject();

source
  .switchMap((val) => Rx.Observable.interval(5000).map(() => val))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));


Rx.Observable.interval(11000).subscribe(x => source.next(x));
```

see a [demo in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/havulepiqi/1/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mydtwe25/) (rxjs v4, but I guess replacing `flatMapLatest` by `switchMap` should do the trick for v5):

```
const input$ = new Rx.Subject()

const repeatedInput$ = input$.flatMapLatest(input => Rx.Observable.interval(200).map(input))
output$ = Rx.Observable.merge(input$, repeatedInput$)

output$.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, `output`))
input$.onNext(2)
setTimeout(() => input$.onNext(4), 300)
```